# Java Spring Creating database-table from a java class gives BeanCreationException

Tags: java, database, spring

Iam trying to create a table with spring with the @Entity annotation but iam getting error that points to the Map fields. I want a table created with all these fields included if possible and if its not possible then only the validationGroup field.

***The class that i want to create a table for:***

```
@Entity
public class StatementDocument {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

@JsonProperty("text")
private String text;

@JsonProperty("statementMap")
private Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap;

@JsonProperty("fields")
private Map<String, String> fields;

@JsonProperty("validationGroup")
private String validationGroup;

public StatementDocument(@JsonProperty("text")String text,
                         @JsonProperty("statementMap")Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap) {
    this.text = text;
    this.statementMap = statementMap;
}

@JsonCreator
public StatementDocument(@JsonProperty("text")String text,
                         @JsonProperty("statementMap")Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap,
                         @JsonProperty("fields") Map<String,String> fields,
                         @JsonProperty("validationGroup") String validationGroup) {
    this.text = text;
    this.statementMap = statementMap;
    this.fields = fields;
    this.validationGroup=validationGroup;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public Map<String, AggregatedStatement> getStatementMap() {
    return statementMap;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void setStatementMap(Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap) {
    this.statementMap = statementMap;
}

public void addField(String key, String value) {
    if (fields == null){
        fields = new HashMap<>();
    }
    fields.put(key, value);
}

public String getField(String key) {
    return fields.get(key);
}

public Map<String, String> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

public void setFields(Map<String, String> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StatementDocument{" +
            "text='" + text + '\'' +
            ", statementMap=" + statementMap +
            ", fields=" + fields +
            '}';
}
```

***Error iam getting is:***

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: statement_document, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(fields)]
```

***Fullstack trace:***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.fk.textanalys.App.main(App.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: statement_document, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(fields)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

***Update 1:***

I accepted the answer that Simon Martinelli provided for excluding some fields from being created in the table.

***Update 2:***

I decided to go with including the fields with datatype of map in the StatementDocument class. Iam gonna provide the class for AggregatedStatement so that I can get help with the relational mapping.

```
public class AggregatedStatement {

    @JsonProperty("statements")
    private final List<Statement> statements;

    @JsonProperty("outcome")
    private final String outcome;

    public AggregatedStatement(@JsonProperty("statements") List<Statement> statements, 
            @JsonProperty("outcome") String outcome) {
        this.statements = statements;
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

    public List<Statement> getStatements() {
        return statements;
    }

    public String getOutcome() {
        return outcome;
    }

}
```

Comment: For the fields of type Map, what database type would you expect?

Comment: I would expect Strings

Comment: How do you think the mapping from a Map to a String should look like?

Comment: Probably not like that and maybe thats why spring has difficulties with doing it

Answer (score 1):

Your map attributes must be relationship either @ManyToOne/@OnToOne or @OneToMany.

Example with @OneToMany

```
@OneToMany
@MapKey(name = "title")
@JsonProperty("statementMap")
private Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap;
```

The MapKey is the field of AggregatedStatement that should be used as key in the map.

**Edited after comment about exclusion of attributes:**

If you want to exclude some attributes of a Entity use @Transient annotation:

```
@Entity
public class StatementDocument {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

@JsonProperty("text")
private String text;

@Transient
@JsonProperty("statementMap")
private Map<String, AggregatedStatement> statementMap;

@Transient
@JsonProperty("fields")
private Map<String, String> fields;

@JsonProperty("validationGroup")
private String validationGroup;
...
```